# Why can I reference imported style object properties directly but not by reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a helper function to add style imports in react. I want to just say `className={stylesJoin(..args)}` instead of `className={styles.style1 + ' ' + styles.style2 etc..}`

```
const stylesJoin = (...params) => {
  let stylesString = "";

  params.forEach((param) => {
    stylesString += styles.param + " ";
  });

  return stylesString;
};

<div className={stylesJoin("buttonGroup__1", "buttonGroup__2")}>
</div>
```

However, the class contents in HTML is undefined undefined.

I checked to see if params[0] and params[1] are `===` to ButtonGroup__1 & ButtonGroup__2 : they are which do provide desired output if referenced directly, e.g `styles.ButtonGroup__1 + ' ' + styles.ButtonGroup__2`

Comment: If `params` is an array, you can simply use `.join(' ')` to return a space separated string of the elements. `const stylesJoin = (...args) => args.join(' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end result has `undefined` because you are referencing `styles.param` (where does `styles` come from?)

```js
const stylesJoin = (...params) => {
  let stylesString = "";

  params.forEach((param) => {
    stylesString += styles.param + " "; // styles?
  });

  return stylesString;
};
```

Since you are simply joining strings together, your entire function can be simplified to

```js
const stylesJoin = (...params) => params.join(' ');
```

Comment: Thanks, I am a newb. Styles is css module import, any ideas why  (just for info sake)?

Comment: You mean you are importing a module called `styles`? It's a bit unclear

Comment: CSS module imports work by doing: import styles from "./mycss.module.sass". Then reference the css property you want, like className={styles.button}

Comment: Ahh understood - then you'd just pass in those when you call your function: `stylesJoin(styles.buttonGroup__1, styles.buttonGroup__2)`

Comment: Gotcha, is there another way to have styles added on in the function to save typing styles again and again?